# Spring batch multi threaded asynchItemWriter

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I am trying to implement multithreading in spring batch. In my implementation i want

1. Single multithreaded Reader (As we are reading only one file)
2. Multi thread processor and writer

I can't implement general chunking as there reader will be multhreded which i don't want.

So next option is asyncItemProcessor/asynchItemWriter. But what i have seen that reader and writer are single threaded only 'asyncItemProcessor' runs in multiple threads in 'asyncItemProcessor/asynchItemWriter.

Is there is anyway where i can run 'Reader' single threaded and processor and writer as multithreaded ?

Answer (score 1):

> i want
>
> 1. Single multithreaded Reader (As we are reading only one file)
> 2. Multi thread processor and writer
>
> Is there is anyway where i can run 'Reader' single threaded and processor and writer as multithreaded ?

You can use a regular **non** multi-threaded chunk-oriented step with a reader and a AsyncItemProcessor + AsyncItemWriter (those should be used in conjunction) to achieve that.

Comment: can you please share simple xml config for it ? As per i know only AsyncItemProcessor runs using multi threaded , AsyncItemWriter will always be single threaded same as reader.